# with A being something OR with A to be something, which one is correct?

Tags: grammar, expressions

The wavenumber ky = ω/cR with cR being the shear-wave velocity of the bedrock.

OR

The wavenumber ky = ω/cR with cR to be the shear-wave velocity of the bedrock.

I am wondering which expression is correct or more preferred by natives.

Comment: This is really a question about jargon.

Comment: I’d go for:  ***where*** cR ***is*** the shear-wave velocity...

Comment: Very occasionally you might see "...where A **is to be** something**  but I think you'd only get **to be** as part of a list as in "...where A **is to be** something and B **to be** something else". Even then the number of occurrences will be vanishingly small. The normal word is 'being' or, as @Jim says "is".

Comment: Probably this question would be more appropriate in [English learners's SE](https://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using '*to be*' implies something expected rather than a current fact, implying '*due to be*`:

> We expect to have a lot of people come up this weekend with the weather to be quite nice

In mathematics and other sciences, you would either use the present tense as @Jim suggests, '*where `cR` is...*' or write '*The wavenumber `ky = = ω/(cR)`, `cR` being...*'